# using the unix command "source" in ansible

Tags: bash, ansible, dot-source

I have the following ansible playbooks:

runWithDotSlash.yml

```
---
 - hosts: user@myhost.local
   tasks:
   - name: try running a script with dot slash
     command: ./script.sh
```

runWithSource.yml

```
---
 - hosts: user@myhost.local
   tasks:
   - name: try running a script with source
     command: source script.sh
```

When I ssh into user@myhost.local I am taken to the home directory of user and I can run script.sh both with dot slash and with source. However only the first playbook works.

I am running the playbooks with the following command:

```
ansible-playbook runWithDotSlash.yml
ansible-playbook runWithSource.yml
```

The second gives the following error message:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "source script.sh", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

Here is script.sh which is in the home directory of user on myhost

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 > ansible_tempfile
```

Why does source not work? What can I do to make it work?

Comment: you can type the absolute pah ej: /home/user/some_dir/scrit.sh

Comment: thanks for this comment, I think you might be on to something because when I use the full path both scripts fail instead of just one. I will look into this further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`source` is a `bash` command. By default, the `command` module uses `sh`. Calling `bash -c 'source script.sh'` should work.

Comment: in sh the command is `.` (dot). But calling either `.` or `source` with a new shell like that makes zero sense because `source` is supposed to run in the **current shell**